# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint ***'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object error

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, primary-key

I get following error when I try to insert a row in the table:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY
> KEY constraint 'PK_EM_SCHEDULER_POLLS'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
> object 'dbo.EM_SCHEDULER_POLLS'. The duplicate key value is (109303).

The function that causes the error is as follows:

```
    public boolean setPollResults(int nSchedulerControllerPollId, Date dtExecuted, boolean blnSuccess)
    {
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement stmt = null;
            String strSQL;
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO EM_SCHEDULER_POLLS (SCHEDULER_CONTROLLER_POLL_ID  ,DATE_TIME_EXECUTED  ,POLLED_SUCCESSFULLY) VALUES (?,?,?)";

            stmt = this.getConnection().getConnection().prepareStatement(strSQL);

            stmt.setInt(1,nSchedulerControllerPollId);
            stmt.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp( dtExecuted.getTime()));
            stmt.setBoolean(3,blnSuccess);

            boolean blnValue = stmt.executeUpdate()!=0;

             stmt.close();

            return blnValue;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (Logger.isErrorEnabled())
                Logger.error(ex);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This the table design. As you can see I am not trying to insert the value in ID column which is of identity type. The duplicate value **109303** is already in table, but why then this is being generated again?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like someone has reseeded the `IDENTITY`, and so a duplicate value is attempted to be inserted.

Comment: `nSchedulerControllerPollId` isn't the Primary Key here, @SergioArrighi .

Comment: @Larnu It maybe true that someone has reseeded the IDENTITY, since this table was synced with another one using an app. How do I check current identity?

Comment: Using `CHECKIDENT`: [Reporting the current identity value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-reporting-the-current-identity-value)

Comment: @Larnu That was indeed the issue. SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('EM_SCHEDULER_POLLS' ) returned 109303

Comment: @Larnu running DBCC CHECKIDENT ('EM_SCHEDULER_POLLS', RESEED, 136161) solved the issue. Looks like syncing app did not change the identity seed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the identity generator has been reseted. You can try with:

`DBCC CHECKIDENT (table_name, RESEED, 0)`

that resets the counter and instead of `0` put the next value after the greater id value.

Edit: If you run 
`DBCC CHECKIDENT (table_name, RESEED)`
without the third parameter, the database will reset the identity counter automatically.

Comment: But the OP *has* data. This would just cause the error again when they get to a value that is already in the table.

Comment: The reseed value must be greater that the highest value in the table, then the incremental will go forward and not attempt another existing value.

Comment: DBCC CHECKIDENT ('EM_SCHEDULER_POLLS', RESEED, 136161) did solve the issue.